# Data Replace is not working

Tags: javascript

```
var data = this.state.registerMobile;
//My data will be like +91 345 45-567
data.replace('-','');
```

It is not removing '-' and i am trying to remove spaces also in between.It's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you need to assign the result of `replace` to some variable, replace will not do the changes in same variable, it will return the modified value. So use it like this:

```
var data = this.state.registerMobile;
data = data.replace('-', '');
console.log('updated data', data);
```

Check the example:

```js
a = '+91 12345678';

b = a.replace('+', '');

console.log('a', a );

console.log('b', b );
```

Comment: Thanks @Mayank Shukla . I don't know how i made this silly mistake.Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does not change the original string but returns a new one. Its first argument is either of the following:

> **regexp (pattern)**
>
> A RegExp object or literal. The match or matches are replaced with newSubStr or the value returned by the specified function.
>
> **substr (pattern)**
>
> A String that is to be replaced by newSubStr. It is treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular expression. *Only the first occurrence will be replaced.*

So if you want to replace hypens and whitespaces, you have to use the following:

```
var data = this.state.registerMobile;
data = data.replace(/\s|-/g, '');
```